# MVC Frameworks (PHP in this case)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement MVC from scratch in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333093/how-to-implement-mvc-from-scratch-in-php)

Let me get this straight:

Model = your database table name

---

Controller = the middle man between user interaction and application logic

---

View = ??

So is a view a dynamic PHP page or a fragment of HTML?

I'm hoping i can get my head around MVC's quickly because i really want to implement them soon

Comment: view pretty much is for phtml or php generated html, but it can include javascript and etc too

Comment: but is the view the entire page? including script links, menus, footers, etc...?

Comment: Hi, The view starts with <html> and ends with it. And a views contains no code except : existence tests, getters and collection iterators.

Comment: The view is pretty much everything that goes to the user. HTML fragments, your layout, images, javascript, etc.

Comment: @vaugham not necessarily. Those aren't hard and fast rules.

Comment: That's the description of passive WebMVC. In the original pattern the model wasn't shallow or just a database interface, but the actual business logic. Views are an object-structure of UI elements. But in PHP-"MVC" it's really just a template.

Comment: Just to clear something out : most so-called MVC frameworks are bad practices. Controllers should have minimum data, and Views should be classes to call Models and handle variable assignments. So far I've only seen one framework doing this, and are pretty recent those changes .. IMO

Comment: @RafeKettler, it's my "ideal view" ; although "hard rules" is quite difficult with "php". But these are the provided features when you used some templates, like smarty.

Comment: @yoda which framework is that?

Comment: @vaugham agree completely. I prefer to think of them as guidelines :) Sometimes it saves you a bunch of time to break a rule, though, with little harm done.

Comment: (Related) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549857/simple-php-mvc-framework/1549970#1549970

Comment: Please point out why none of the many related questions in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MVC+php did not already answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following explanation of MVC is taken from the codeigniter user guide.

- The Model represents your data structures. Typically your model classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and update information in your database.
- The View is the information that is being presented to a user. A View will normally be a web page. A view can also be a page fragment like a header or footer. It can also be an RSS page, or any other type of "page".
- The Controller serves as an intermediary between the Model, the View, and any other resources needed to process the HTTP request and generate a web page.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

**Edit: Example of what you may include in each entity**

*Controller (this file is targeted by the browser)*

```
<?php
    //Assuming that the database has already been connected

    //Include the model
    require('members_model.php');
    //Get the posts made by a particular user from the database)
    $posts = $this->members_model->get_posts($_POST['member_id']);
    //Output the view
    require('members_posts.php');
?>
```

*Model*

```
<?php
    class members_model {

        //Function to get all the posts made by a particular member
        public function get_posts($member_id) {
            $query = mysql_query("
                SELECT *
                FROM Posts
                WHERE author = ".$member_id
            );
            return mysql_fetch_array($query);
        }

    }
?>
```

*View*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>All posts by member</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            <h1><?=$post['title']?></h1>
            <span><?=$post['date']?></span>
            <?=$post['body']?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, this is an **extremely** simplified example but hopefully this gives you a rough idea of what should be going where.

Comment: The name of the model should technically be "posts_model" since it is dealing with the posts database, not the members but for simplicity sake, lets call it "members_model".

Comment: Too bad that the CI guys apparently got MVC completely wrong. The Model is not just the Database.

Comment: In most PHP use where MVC is used to separate code, the model is generally only used for connecting to data sources. This could either be a database, YQL queries, XML feeds or any other source. I know it's not true MVC but I believe that's the most popular use for the model.

Comment: The Model is not just the persistence layer or Webservices. It's wrong and it is a shame that frameworks like Rails, Cake and CI make people believe that just because they use ActiveRecord, which btw CI defines wrong as well.

Answer (score 1):

Models are the data and the DB. The controller intermediates between model and view. The views are typically (in PHP) HTML with some PHP mixed in. Think of the view as a template for the site. The view is responsible for rendering the data from the model into a suitable user interface.

The view is typically a system of different HTML/PHP pages (a template for the header, one for the footer, one for the body, and more for different aspects of the site).

**EDIT** here's a basic example of how you might write a view for a menu:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<?php
// Say menu_items is an array mapping links to the text they should use
foreach($menu_items as $link => $text){
    echo "<a href=\"$link\">$text</a>";
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ok cool, so how to you code a menu system, could you give me an example of a < href=??>Link</a> to another "View"?

Comment: are you sure you can use a syntax like: **as $link, $text** in PHP ?

Comment: @mailo that's my fault. I'm more used to Python. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The view knows how to display the data.  The view knows you want to color some values red, and display these values as a list, and you want to use drag-and-drop to rearrange a list.  It doesn't know where these values come from, so you can focus on the layout and user interaction.

The controller doesn't know any of that specific layout or behavior stuff. The controller only knows how to give the view values, how to save the order of the list, etc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a template language in itself since it can be used with html , although there other template solution available such as smarty (which are designer friendly) .Bassicaly in your view you would be doing
consing fil Foo.phtml

```
<p>Welcome <?= $this->username ?> </p>
```

Your View Class might have function loadView() inside which

```
   class My_View
    {
    public $data;
    public $view;

    public function __set($property,$value)
{
$data[$preperty] = $value;
}

public function __get($property)
{
return $data[$preperty];
}


    public function loadView()
    {
    ob_start();
    include('Foo.phtml');
    $this->view = $ob_get_clean();

    }

public function __toString()
{
return $this->view;
}
    }
```

In your controller class

```
class My_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
  $view = new My_View();
$view->username = "jason bouren";
$view->loadView();
echo $view;
}
}
```

Most of the php MVC framework work this way . Inside Controller class you can create model object and use it . (All the code I have writter for explaining purpose only it has been not tested )