# Adding pages to a single page Bootstrap website?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

What's the best way to add pages to a single page Bootstrap website? Right now I have a single index.html page using a header menu and scrool blocks, but I need to add external pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can beginning with download some twitter Bootstrap template. For example from:

> http://startbootstrap.com/

And see how it's organize. Be familiar with this cases and after try to use some framework like Angular (javascript), Symfony2 (PHP), or implement your own MVC architecture with PHP:

> [How to implement MVC from scratch in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333093/how-to-implement-mvc-from-scratch-in-php)

But you need practices. At the beginning, you can juste do this:

```
/-- Root
--------- index.html
--------- page2.html
```

and link to `page2.html` from your index like this: `<a href="page2.html">Page 2 !</a>`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question. For example you can use a button to navigate to another site.

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="another.html">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what we (developpers) often refer to as [SAP (Single Page Application)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and there are many framework to help you not to start from scratch, see [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org) as one of them... It's the one I use for such purpose, yet, there are others like [emberjs](http://emberjs.com), [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done this way, but like it's said - it is a very general question.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```